# Laravel CRUD in a single view

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-blade, dashboard

In Laravel, I want this button to receive the ID of my object to display its information in a modal that appears when I click on it.

My AnnonceAdminController

Here is the controller that manages my users' sales advertisements on the internet.

I want the edit and delete buttons to open the modal that displays information about the object in the table of my dashboard.

So that I can edit and delete on the same blade view/page.

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use App\Models\Annonces;
use App\Models\Categories;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;

class AnnonceAdminController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     */
    public function index()
    {
        //
        $annonces = Annonces::orderBy('updated_at', 'DESC')->paginate(5);

        return view('admin.annonce.index', compact('annonces'));
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     */
    public function create()
    {
        //
        $annonce = Annonces::All();

        $categories = Categories::orderBy('nom', 'asc')->get();

        return view('admin.annonce.ajouter', compact(
            'annonce',
            'categories'
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //
        // dd($request);

        // création d'une instance de class (model Annonces) pour enregistrer en base .
        $newAnnonce = new Annonces;

        $newAnnonce->category_id = $request->category;

        $newAnnonce->user_id =  Auth::user()->id;

        $newAnnonce->nom = $request->nom;
        $newAnnonce->description = $request->description;
        $newAnnonce->prix = $request->prix;

        // Traitement de l'upload de 'image
        if ($request->file()) {
            $fileName = $request->image->store('public/images/annonces');
            $newAnnonce->image = $fileName;
        }
        // Enregistrement des données
        $newAnnonce->save();

        return Redirect::route('admin.annonce.index');
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     */
    public function show(string $id)
    {
        // Voir une annonce
        $showAnnonce = Annonces::findOrFail($id);

        // dd($showAnnonce);

        return view('admin.annonce.show', compact(
            'showAnnonce',
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     */
    public function edit(string $id)
    {
        //
        $editAnnonce = Annonces::findOrFail($id);

        $categories = Categories::orderBy('nom', 'asc')->get();

        return view('admin.annonce.ajouter', compact(
            'editAnnonce',
            'categories'
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     */
    public function update(Request $request, string $id)
    {
        //
        $editAnnonce = Annonces::findOrFail($id);

        $editAnnonce->category_id = $request->category;

        $editAnnonce->user_id = Auth::user()->id;

        $editAnnonce->nom = $request->nom;
        $editAnnonce->description = $request->description;
        $editAnnonce->prix = $request->prix;

        // Traitement de l'upload de 'image
        if ($request->file()) {

            if ($editAnnonce->image != '') {
                Storage::delete($editAnnonce->image);
            }

            $fileName = $request->image->store('public/images/annonces');
            $editAnnonce->image = $fileName;
        }

        $editAnnonce->save();
        return Redirect::route('admin.annonce.index');
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     */
    public function delete(string $id)
    {
        //
        $deleteAnnonce = Annonces::findOrFail($id);

        $deleteAnnonce->delete();

        return redirect(route('admin.annonce.index'));
    }
}
```

My button

```html
<button type="button" id="updateProductButton"
    data-drawer-target="drawer-update-product-default"
    data-drawer-show="drawer-update-product-default"
    aria-controls="drawer-update-product-default" data-drawer-placement="right"
    class="inline-flex items-center px-3 py-2 text-sm font-medium text-center text-white rounded-lg bg-blue-700 hover:bg-blue-800 focus:ring-4 focus:ring-blue-300 dark:bg-blue-600 dark:hover:bg-blue-700 dark:focus:ring-blue-800">
    <svg class="w-4 h-4" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 20 20"
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <path
            d="M17.414 2.586a2 2 0 00-2.828 0L7 10.172V13h2.828l7.586-7.586a2 2 0 000-2.828z">
        </path>
        <path fill-rule="evenodd"
            d="M2 6a2 2 0 012-2h4a1 1 0 010 2H4v10h10v-4a1 1 0 112 0v4a2 2 0 01-2 2H4a2 2 0 01-2-2V6z"
            clip-rule="evenodd"></path>
    </svg>
</button>
```

My form modal

```html
<!-- Edit Product Drawer -->
<div id="drawer-update-product-default"
    class="fixed top-0 right-0 z-40 w-full h-screen max-w-xs p-4 overflow-y-auto transition-transform translate-x-full bg-white dark:bg-gray-800"
    tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="drawer-label" aria-hidden="true">
    <h5 id="drawer-label"
        class="inline-flex items-center mb-6 text-sm font-semibold text-gray-500 uppercase dark:text-gray-400">Update
        Product</h5>
    <button type="button" data-drawer-dismiss="drawer-update-product-default"
        aria-controls="drawer-update-product-default"
        class="text-gray-400 bg-transparent hover:bg-gray-200 hover:text-gray-900 rounded-lg text-sm p-1.5 absolute top-2.5 right-2.5 inline-flex items-center dark:hover:bg-gray-600 dark:hover:text-white">
        <svg aria-hidden="true" class="w-5 h-5" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 20 20"
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <path fill-rule="evenodd"
                d="M4.293 4.293a1 1 0 011.414 0L10 8.586l4.293-4.293a1 1 0 111.414 1.414L11.414 10l4.293 4.293a1 1 0 01-1.414 1.414L10 11.414l-4.293 4.293a1 1 0 01-1.414-1.414L8.586 10 4.293 5.707a1 1 0 010-1.414z"
                clip-rule="evenodd"></path>
        </svg>
        <span class="sr-only">Close menu</span>
    </button>
    <form action="#">
        <div class="space-y-4">
            <div>
                <label for="name"
                    class="block mb-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 dark:text-white">Name</label>
                <input type="text" name="title" id="name"
                    class="bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 text-sm rounded-lg focus:ring-blue-600 focus:border-blue-600 block w-full p-2.5 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:border-gray-600 dark:placeholder-gray-400 dark:text-white dark:focus:ring-blue-500 dark:focus:border-blue-500"
                    value="Education Dashboard" placeholder="Type product name" required="">
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="category"
                    class="block mb-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 dark:text-white">Technology</label>
                <select id="category"
                    class="bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 text-sm rounded-lg focus:ring-blue-500 focus:border-blue-500 block w-full p-2.5 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:border-gray-600 dark:placeholder-gray-400 dark:text-white dark:focus:ring-blue-500 dark:focus:border-blue-500">
                    <option selected="">Flowbite</option>
                    <option value="RE">React</option>
                    <option value="AN">Angular</option>
                    <option value="VU">Vue JS</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="price"
                    class="block mb-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 dark:text-white">Price</label>
                <input type="number" name="price" id="price"
                    class="bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 text-sm rounded-lg focus:ring-blue-600 focus:border-blue-600 block w-full p-2.5 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:border-gray-600 dark:placeholder-gray-400 dark:text-white dark:focus:ring-blue-500 dark:focus:border-blue-500"
                    value="2999" placeholder="$149" required="">
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="description"
                    class="block mb-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 dark:text-white">Description</label>
                <textarea id="description" rows="4"
                    class="block p-2.5 w-full text-sm text-gray-900 bg-gray-50 rounded-lg border border-gray-300 focus:ring-blue-500 focus:border-blue-500 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:border-gray-600 dark:placeholder-gray-400 dark:text-white dark:focus:ring-blue-500 dark:focus:border-blue-500"
                    placeholder="Enter event description here">Start developing with an open-source library of over 450+ UI components, sections, and pages built with the utility classes from Tailwind CSS and designed in Figma.</textarea>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="discount"
                    class="block mb-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 dark:text-white">Discount</label>
                <select id="discount"
                    class="bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 text-sm rounded-lg focus:ring-blue-500 focus:border-blue-500 block w-full p-2.5 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:border-gray-600 dark:placeholder-gray-400 dark:text-white dark:focus:ring-blue-500 dark:focus:border-blue-500">
                    <option selected="">No</option>
                    <option value="5">5%</option>
                    <option value="10">10%</option>
                    <option value="20">20%</option>
                    <option value="30">30%</option>
                    <option value="40">40%</option>
                    <option value="50">50%</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="bottom-0 left-0 flex justify-center w-full pb-4 mt-4 space-x-4 sm:absolute sm:px-4 sm:mt-0">
            <button type="submit"
                class="w-full justify-center text-white bg-blue-700 hover:bg-blue-800 focus:ring-4 focus:outline-none focus:ring-blue-300 font-medium rounded-lg text-sm px-5 py-2.5 text-center dark:bg-blue-600 dark:hover:bg-blue-700 dark:focus:ring-blue-800">
                Update
            </button>
            <button type="button"
                class="w-full justify-center text-red-600 inline-flex items-center hover:text-white border border-red-600 hover:bg-red-600 focus:ring-4 focus:outline-none focus:ring-red-300 font-medium rounded-lg text-sm px-5 py-2.5 text-center dark:border-red-500 dark:text-red-500 dark:hover:text-white dark:hover:bg-red-600 dark:focus:ring-red-900">
                <svg aria-hidden="true" class="w-5 h-5 mr-1 -ml-1" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 20 20"
                    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                    <path fill-rule="evenodd"
                        d="M9 2a1 1 0 00-.894.553L7.382 4H4a1 1 0 000 2v10a2 2 0 002 2h8a2 2 0 002-2V6a1 1 0 100-2h-3.382l-.724-1.447A1 1 0 0011 2H9zM7 8a1 1 0 012 0v6a1 1 0 11-2 0V8zm5-1a1 1 0 00-1 1v6a1 1 0 102 0V8a1 1 0 00-1-1z"
                        clip-rule="evenodd"></path>
                </svg>
                Delete
            </button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: What's stopping you from adding the id to another `data-*` attribute? `data-object-id="{{ $object->id }}"`